# How to get Android user/phone info when installed my app

Tags: android

whenever user installs my android app, i should get their device info and i like to maintain a webservice about the user who installed my app..is this possible?, is it valid to do that..in general does App development companies will have the user info who installed their app?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, developers keep anonymous statistics, or identify individual users using the IMEI number or the wifi/bluetooth MAC address. It is generally a very bad practice to use the user's phone number. Rule of the thumb is that if you want personal contact details like the phone number or email address, you explicitly ask the user the enter them, and take their permission to use then for whatever purposes. You should **never** take personal information from the user without their consent.

Comment: so i can keep track of users IMEI numbers who installed my app, any clue how to do that

Comment: Use the Android API to get the number, and store it on a server along with other usage data. Note that tablets will not have an IMEI number, and due to that some developers use the wifi/bluetooth MAC address.